# Adding a field to the jq output adds rows

Tags: jq

I have the following command:

> `kubectl get pod -A -o=json | jq -r '[.items[]|select(any( .status.containerStatuses[]; .state.waiting or (.state.terminated and .state.terminated.reason!=\"Completed\")))|{pod:.metadata.name, namespace:.metadata.namespace}]'`

This works just like I want (except I need to add a field).  This is an excerpt from the results:

```
{
  "pod": "ops-test-app-blue-54556c9b8b-pq6hd",
  "namespace": "software-operations-test-apps"
},
{
  "pod": "ops-test-app-blue-54556c9b8b-vknl8",
  "namespace": "software-operations-test-apps"
}
```

When I add the extra field I need it ends up looking like this:

> `kubectl get pod -A -o=json | jq -r '[.items[]|select(any( .status.containerStatuses[]; .state.waiting or (.state.terminated and .state.terminated.reason!=\"Completed\")))|{pod:.metadata.name, container:.status.containerStatuses[].name, namespace:.metadata.namespace}]'`

This is the same command, except it adds the container name to the json output.  However, when I do that, it adds extra results (as well as my extra field):

```
{
  "pod": "ops-test-app-blue-54556c9b8b-pq6hd",
  "container": "ops-test-app-blue",
  "namespace": "software-operations-test-apps"
},
{
  "pod": "ops-test-app-blue-54556c9b8b-pq6hd",
  "container": "istio-proxy",
  "namespace": "software-operations-test-apps"
},
{
  "pod": "ops-test-app-blue-54556c9b8b-vknl8",
  "container": "ops-test-app-blue",
  "namespace": "software-operations-test-apps"
},
{
  "pod": "ops-test-app-blue-54556c9b8b-vknl8",
  "container": "istio-proxy",
  "namespace": "software-operations-test-apps"
}
```

The extra results are the rows with the container set to istio-proxy.  This seems to be because there are 2 entries in each instance of `.status.containerStatuses`.  One for the ops-test-app-blue container and one for the istio-proxy app.

But when I look at the data for the istio-proxy instance, it does not match the criteria.  Here is an example of the full json for the istio-proxy instance:

```
{
    "containerID": "docker://b99e580b64bb70ba1ddbfc726688e8901d05975c097ec55625cad971994c38a8",
    "image": "istio/proxyv2:1.10.0",
    "imageID": "docker-pullable://istio/proxyv2@sha256:88c6c693e67a0f2492191a0e7d8020ddc85603bfc704f252655cb9eb5eeb3f58",
    "lastState": {},
    "name": "istio-proxy",
    "ready": true,
    "restartCount": 0,
    "started": true,
    "state": {
        "running": {
            "startedAt": "2022-01-06T23:52:10Z"
        }
    }
}
```

It has a `state.running`.  (Not `state.waiting` or `state.terminated` as the select statement is using for its filtering).

Why are these extra rows being added?

**And is there a way to get the extra field, but not the extra rows?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're filtering the wrong thing.

```
.items |
map (
   .status.containerStatuses |= map(
      select(
         (  .state.waiting
         or .state.terminated and .state.terminated.reason != "Completed"
         )
      )
   ) |
   {
      pod:       .metadata.name,
      namespace: .metadata.namespace,
      container: .status.containerStatuses[].name
   }
)
```